# Could not load library "$libdir/pg_stat_plans" while upgrading 9.3 to 9.4

Tags: postgresql

Library issue while upgrading postgres 9.3.4 to 9.4

I'm trying to upgrade postgres 9.3.4 to postgres 9.4 but im getting below error.

```
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/ --new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/ --old-datadir=/crpjirw1/postgres1/9.3/data/ --new-datadir=/crpjirw1/postgres1/9.4/data/ --check       

Performing Consistency Checks     

Checking cluster versions                                   ok     
Checking database user is a superuser                       ok    
Checking database connection settings                       ok    
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok    
Checking for reg* system OID user data types                ok    
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok    
Checking for invalid "line" user columns                    ok    
Checking for presence of required libraries                 fatal    

Your installation references loadable libraries that are missing from the
new installation.  You can add these libraries to the new installation,
or remove the functions using them from the old installation.  A list of
problem libraries is in the file:    
loadable_libraries.txt    

Failure, exiting

more loadable_libraries.txt

Could not load library "$libdir/pg_stat_plans"
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_stat_plans": No such file or 
directory
```

i checked in libdir there is no file pg_stat_plans

```
 pg_config  --pkglibdir      

/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib    

cd /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib    
ls -lrt pg_stat_plan

ls: cannot access pg_stat_plan*: No such file or directory
```

I dont understand where its looking for pg_stat_plan lib file.
Someone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue.

Dropped the pg_stat_plans extension to fix the issue.

There is multiples function will be associated to pg_stat_plans extension

**drop extension**  worked even though there is no extension like pg_stat_plans and it automatically dropped all function and views associated with extension and fixed the issue.

So we have to uninstall the rpm package pg_stat_plans.xxxxx.rpm first and then drop extension and trigger pg_upgrade , it worked for me.